# How to check if a button is clicked or not before sending AJAX request using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button which needs to have been clicked by user before submitting the form which is as:

```
$('#chooseButton')
    .on(
        'click',
        function() {
    console.log("user had pressed the button");
    });
```

I have a submit button which is:

```
<button id="saveBtn" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Submit</button>
```

When i click the **submit** button then the action it goes to here:

```
 $("#saveBtn").click(function (e) {


    e.preventDefault();
    let allValid = true;
    $("form").each(function (index, form) {
        allValid = allValid && form.reportValidity();
    });

    if (!jQuery('#chooseButton').data('clicked')) {
        alert("please select the selection");
    } else if (allValid && jQuery('#chooseButton').data('clicked')) {
        /*$.ajax({
          // ajax code to submit
        }); */
    } else {

    }

});
```

If the button is not clicked,then it shows me **alert("please select the selection")** but even if the button is clicked,it is showing me same **alert**. It needs to go to else..if part if button has been clicked,but it is not going in else..if part if button is clicked.How to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a boolean and make it true on click

```js
var clicked="false"
$('#chooseButton')
    .on(
        'click',
        function() {
    console.log("user had pressed the button");
    clicked=true;
    });
$("#saveBtn").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let allValid = true;
    $("form").each(function (index, form) {
        allValid = allValid && form.reportValidity();
    });

    if (!clicked) {
        alert("please select the selection");
    } else if (allValid && jQuery('#chooseButton').data('clicked')) {
        /*$.ajax({
          // ajax code to submit
        }); */
    } else {

    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="chooseButton">Click</button>
<button id="saveBtn" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `variable`, And can set a `Boolean` value to detect the button clicked status, like this,

```
var chooseButtonClicked = false;

$('#chooseButton')
    .on(
        'click',
        function() {
    chooseButtonClicked = true;
    });

$("#saveBtn").click(function (e) {


    e.preventDefault();
    let allValid = true;
    $("form").each(function (index, form) {
        allValid = allValid && form.reportValidity();
    });

    if (!chooseButtonClicked ) {
        alert("please select the selection");
    } else if (allValid && chooseButtonClicked) {
        /*$.ajax({
          // ajax code to submit
        }); */
    } else {

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a flag variable and set it true on click of button.

```
var buttonClickFlag = false; 

$('#chooseButton')
.on(
    'click',
    function() {
     buttonClickFlag = true;
     console.log("user had pressed the button");
});
```

And Before AJAX call, you can check the value of variable 'buttonClickFlag'. if the value is true then call otherwise not.